# In xskak & chessboard, how to use a variable's value for the moves?

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I am using the packages `xskak` and `chessboard`.

How should I first define a variable to hold the moves, then use that variable when using `\hidemoves` and `\mainline`?

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSF,T1]{fontenc} % use fontenc before chessboard
\usepackage{chessboard,xskak}
\setboardfontencoding{LSF}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame[]
\def\mvs{1.e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6}
\hidemoves{\mvs}
\chessboard{}
\mainline{\mvs}
\end{document}
```

I have tried with `\def` and with `newcommand`. Each demands braces around the value to be assigned; I have tried both as shown and with a second pair of braces, in case the value itself needs to contain braces. Neither works.

In the calls to `\hidemoves` and `\mainline`, I have tried both putting braces around `\mvs` and omitting them.

Every time, the engine gives the message:

Argument of \EatNumberA has an extra }.

Comment: you can't do this. By storing the text in a command you are freezing the catcodes and then e.g. the mate symbol will not longer work. If you want to save and reuse a game use the tools of xskak.

Comment: But in simple cases `\expandafter\mainline\expandafter{\mvs} ` can work.